# Web Flow crashes on appended variable

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-webflow-2

I'm currently facing a problem using Spring Web Flows 2.0.7, the webflow crashes, when a variable is submitted. The corresponding webflow looks like this:

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

  <!-- some model, i use below -->
  <var name="register"
       class="org.zcore.conference.Registration" />

  <!-- my input id -->
  <input type="long" name="conId" value="flowScope.conId"/>

  <!-- my first view state -->
  <view-state id="register" model="register">
  <!-- imagine much more stuff here -->
</flow>
```

When entering the flow with an appended conId (http://localhost:8080/app/myflow?conId=123) the following error pops up:

```
2012-08-07 17:33:34,583 WARN 25205715@qtp-28882952-5 com.coremedia.cae.webflow.AbstractFlowViewController - Error handling flow request: 'Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable': /app/flow
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
```

I'm pretty surprised, that the supplied value does not seem to be serializable, as it is a simple int value. Looks like I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure org.zcore.conference.Registration is serializable
if it is, then it is probably another object in your view state that is not

Comment: Basically right. Unluckily all other objects implement Serializable.

Comment: Unluckily not yet. I tried to rewrite the whole thing from scratch. My (dirty) temporary fix is not using webflows right now.